# Internet Explorer: Unable to add a site to a security zone

Tags: internet-explorer, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I am unable to add any site to the IE security zone.

[image]

I keep getting this option.
There is no option to add a site to the security zone.
I am trying this from my domain controller also, with the domain administrator, and still not able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are grayed out because the settings are controlled by group policy. If you enabled this policy, it will prevent users from adding or removing sites from security zones: [Security Zones: Do not allow users to add/delete sites](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::Security_zones_map_edit). You can check the related group policy and registry setting.

If you want to add sites to IE security zone, you can try to disable the above group policy or configure this group policy directly: [Site to Zone Assignment List](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::IZ_Zonemaps). You can enable this policy setting and enter a list of sites and their related zone numbers.

[image]